# spring 4 - Found interface org.springframework.test.context.TestContext, but class was expected

Tags: java, spring, maven

I started to get "`Found interface org.springframework.test.context.TestContext, but class was expected`" exception after spring core migration from 3.2 to 4. I'm using `mvn clean test` and java 7 as maven compiler version.

any ideas what to do with that?

Comment: You are probably mixing spring versions, don't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fixed.

It was problem with spring test db unit library. Some description of problem here https://github.com/springtestdbunit/spring-test-dbunit/issues/46 - current version visible in maven repos 1.0.1 is not working with spring 4. So I needed to clone repo and build version 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Phew!  Thanks for coming back and posting that answer - had me stumped for a bit.